# How can I use jQuery Mobile to show a gif on touch?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-mobile, touch, gif

On a desktop, my code works. I need to adapt it for mobile and am not having any luck. I tried jQuery mobile tap and taphold without any luck.

I would like the user to be able to tap anywhere on the screen and show a hidden image. I actually have about 20 divs,each containing an image, but I want to only show one at a time. For desktop, I am using keyup/keydown and it works perfectly.

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/rewinn/3gc202z5/)

```
<div class="photo" data-key="1">
    <img class="item" data-id="image">
</div>


$(window).on('keydown', function(e) {
    $(data-key=" ' + e.which + ' ").show();
```

Comment: did you try the touchstart event? a jsfiddle would help.

Comment: @Sushil Thanks for the quick response.  I added a Fiddle.

Comment: Can you replace $.mobile.loading().hide(); with $.mobile.loading('hide');

Comment: It didn't.  I also tried $.mobile.loader('hide');  but it caused "Loading" to appear.  I'm new to jQuery, so I appreciate the help. I'm going to try hammer.js tonight and see what I can get working. @Sushil

Comment: Hi @Rachel, in your jsfiddle I dont see any reference to jquery. also can you try to add an image so that i can see something in the output on the right. it will help. I always use touchstart for touch based devices. even hammer.js is good. u can use the doubletap event in it.

Comment: Try something like this: http://jsfiddle.net/ezanker/3gc202z5/1/

Comment: Thanks, @ezanker.  It didn't work for me.  I really appreciate it.  I am determined to figure this out.  I'll be sure to post my results when I do.

Comment: What did not work? In the fiddle if you click on a square and hold, the pictures shows, then if you click and hold another square, the other picture hides and a new picture is shown...

Answer (score 0):

SOLVED! I'm new to programming, so I don't know if this is the smartest way to go about it and would love feedback for a smarter solution. Thanks, @Sushil for suggesting touchstart. And thanks, @ezanker. Your code worked perfectly in the fiddle. I was certainly implementing something wrong on my end. Here's what I did:

```
var tapStart = function() {
    var randomGfy = Math.floor(Math.random() * $('.gfy').length);
    $('.gfy').hide().eq(randomGfy).show();      
}

var tapEnd = function() {
    $(randomGfy).hide();
}

var init = function() {
    $(window).bind('touchstart',tapStart).bind('touchend',tapEnd);  
}

init();
```